# Infopath and field for content type

Tags: infopath, content-type, custom-form

I have created different content types in SharePoint.

Then I started editing the different forms for content types in InfoPath. The only field that is not visible is 'Content type'.

Why can't I see content type under fields? How can I add content type as a field to the InfoPath form?

E.g. if a employee choose the wrong form and have to change content type, then it's not possible to do that in the form.

Best regards
Morten

Comment: The form is based on a content type. It is direct linked to this. I think that is why it is not available in the form itself. If there was an option to change the CT then the form you are in would be invalid.